# Generic click event in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton, onclicklistener

Recently I was able to create a tablet software for my Cerebral Palsy girl to "talk" to me, since she can't speak.

Well, a friend of mine has Amyothrophic Lateral Sclerosis (ALS). He can move just one finger and he is willing to use my daughter's software to be able to "talk" again.

Since he can move just a finger, I created a version where each item "blinks" (in yellow) for some time (just one second) and if he presses a mouse button, the item focused (in yellow) is activated.

See below:

[image: Communication software]

It works if you leave the mouse over the black portion of the screen. If mouse is over the buttons, it won't work, it will click the button where the mouse is over.

Also, if he uses a keyboard and he presses the ENTER key, it will activate the first button, then, if he clicks the left arrow and then presses the ENTER again, it will activate the second button and so on.

So, I wish I could create an generic event that if he would press the ENTER key, just the selected (in yellow) item would be activated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could make two different modes. One where there are click listeners for each picture,and another where simply a click anywhere on the screen is recognized ( ex. find the largest layout id and set a listener).  Then in the second mode, use

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

to detect KeyEvents such as Enter, and handle them depending on the highlighted View.